# Apache poi sparklines

Tags: apache-poi

there is a "new" feature in Excel 2010 called sparklines. I could not find something about it regarding Apache POI. It looks like Apache POI does not support this feature. Am I right ?

Looks like this:

https://goo.gl/djnQSX

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which file format - `.xls` or `.xlsx`? And what support do you need? Read? Write? Change?

Comment: Format is .xlsx and I need to write - generate the .xlsx file with sparklines.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You are completely right!

The [Apache POI library](https://poi.apache.org/index.html) has no support for SparkLines or other kind of chart as it's explained in their [limitations page](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html).

However if you just want to change/read/write the data behind the chart you can use POI anyway.

If you want or need something else like change the style or the range with chart data, it's no so hard to make some code to manage this kind of graphs.

Just by doing the next:

1. Change the extension of the Excel file from 'xlsx' to 'zip'
2. Unzip the file content.
3. Identify the number of the Sheet where your Sparkline is by editing the file 'xl/workbook.xml' and looking for a text similar to: ""
4. Then edit the file with that sheet info ('xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml' in the example).
5. Look for the code of the SparkLines (usally at the end of the file). It should looks like this:

```html
<ext uri="{05C60535-1F16-4fd2-B633-F4F36F0B64E0}" xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main">
  <x14:sparklineGroups xmlns:xm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2006/main">
   <x14:sparklineGroup displayEmptyCellsAs="gap">
    <x14:colorSeries theme="4" tint="-0.499984740745262"/>
    <x14:colorNegative theme="5"/>
    <x14:colorAxis rgb="FF000000"/>
    <x14:colorMarkers theme="4" tint="-0.499984740745262"/>
    <x14:colorFirst theme="4" tint="0.39997558519241921"/>
    <x14:colorLast theme="4" tint="0.39997558519241921"/>
    <x14:colorHigh theme="4"/>
    <x14:colorLow theme="4"/>
    <x14:sparklines>
     <x14:sparkline>
      <xm:f>Sheet3!A2:A25</xm:f>
      <xm:sqref>B3</xm:sqref>
     </x14:sparkline>
    </x14:sparklines>
   </x14:sparklineGroup>
  </x14:sparklineGroups>
 </ext>
```

6. There you can edit the style info and data of the sparkline chart as you want/need.
7. Save the changes.
8. Compress again with ZIP all the folders and files.
9. Change the extension to 'xlsx' again.

You can do all this tasks with code.

I hope this helps

Comment: Hello Fran,

It sounds like a nice idea how to solve my issue. I have not tried it yet, but the time is coming. I will write here then.

Thanks a lot for the advice!